# Update Value in a Map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, int, set

I'm trying to update a value in a Map that has a many-to-one relationship.

```
| Keys | Values |
| 1    | {1, 2} |
| 2    | {1, 2} |
| 3    | {3}    |
```

Keys 1 and 2 refer to the same set. I want to merge the sets of keys 2 and 3. Such that I get the following:

```
| Keys | Values    |
| 1    | {1, 2, 3} |
| 2    | {1, 2, 3} |
| 3    | {1, 2, 3} |
```

Is there a way to do this without getting O(n)?

What I have so far:

```
// Merge sets for keys i and j
Map[Integer, Set[Integer]] map;
map.get(i).addAll(map.get(j));
for(int key : map.get(j)) map.put(key, map.get(i));
```

Comment: So you want all your keys to refer to the same value set?

Comment: That's right. I want to mutate the reference of map.get(3) to refer to the same Object as referenced by map.get(1) and map.get(2).

Edit: It's easy in this case because you can do map.put(3, map.get(1)) or map.put(3, map.get(2)), but I want a general solution for merging the set of key j with set of key i. It gets tricky as the disjoint sets get large.

Comment: this works but i dont know abt time complexity  `Set<Integer> finalSet = new HashSet<>();
        for(int key : map.keySet()) {
            Set<Integer> value = map.get(key);
            finalSet.addAll(value);
        }
        for(int key : map.keySet()) {
            map.put(key, finalSet);
        }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a  `union–find data structure` to solve your problem.

> It supports two useful operations:
>
> Find: Determine which subset a particular element is in. Find typically returns an item from this set that serves as its "representative"; by comparing the result of two Find operations, one can determine whether two elements are in the same subset.
>
> Union: Join two subsets into a single subset.
>
> Just applying this technique alone yields a worst-case running-time of `O(log n)` per MakeSet, Union, or Find operation.

```
function MakeSet(x)
    x.parent := x

function Find(x)
    if x.parent == x
        return x
    else
        return Find(x.parent)

function Union(x, y)
    xRoot := Find(x)
    yRoot := Find(y)
    xRoot.parent := yRoot
```

Detail for [Disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), [UnionFind Algorithms](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Ers/AlgsDS07/01UnionFind.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. I knew I had to implement a disjoint-set structure, but I wanted to see if it were possible to do it using a HashMap to keep O(1) search time.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there: since keys 1 and 2 already refer to the same set, you only have to add the elements of set from key 3, and then make key 3 refer to your merged result.

```
// Merge sets for keys i and j
Map[Integer, Set[Integer]] map;
map.get(i).addAll(map.get(j));
map.put(j, map.get(i));
```

Unless I missed a subtlety in your question?

**Edit**: I missed a subtlety: this works only when adding a single element to the set. If `map.get(j)` has more than one element, I see no way of escaping the loop you suggested in the question.

Comment: I was sitting here thinking the same. Not sure if I'm missing the real problem to the question.

Comment: @Pumphouse No, I was wrong. The example caused my mistake: with `j = 3`, there are indeed no problem, but with a larger sample (e.g. {1,2,3} and {4,5}), merging does require the O(n). I'll add a note to my answer.